# Replace sshd_config file with the custom one in Yocto

Tags: yocto, sshd, yocto-recipe

I use Yocto Zeus to build an embedded Linux for my board. So far I need to replace the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with my custom one.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any useful information about that. Just found some help on the Internet.
I've created a custom layer and add an recipe as following:

```
sources
  mylayer
    mylayer-recipes
      recipes-connectivity
        openssh
          openssh_%.bbappend
          openssh
            sshd_config
```

**openssh_%.bbappend**

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://sshd_config"
```

after this I've try to rebuild the image

```
`bitbake core-image-minimal`
```

But nothing happens. No error and no change of the sshd_config file in the image.

What I do wrong? Actually I only want to replace the system `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with the custom one, nothing else.

Comment: what does `bitbake-layers show-appends | grep openssh` show?

Comment: Shows nothing. But what does it mean? My bbappend isn't visible for bitbake? How can I feed it to bitbake?  I've never actually done this either and I haven't worked much with Yocto.

Comment: That is correct. I can see you've figured out the folders structure did not match.

Comment: Yes, I just tried different options and suddenly it worked. thank you @OleksandrKravchuk for your participation and for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've finally solved the issue. It's turned out that I haven't follow the full path to the *.bb but only the top level although the doc says *"...This implies that you must have the supporting directory structure set up that will contain any files or patches you will be including from the layer."* in the `5.1.5. Using .bbappend Files` section. So the final folders structure looks like this:

```
sources
  mylayer
    mylayer-recipes          
        openssh
          openssh_%.bbappend
          openssh
            sshd_config <----- the file that replaces the original one

  poky
    recipes-connectivity
      openssh
        openssh_8.0p1.bb
        openssh
          sshd_config   <----- the original file
          ....
```

i.e. I just added folder `openssh` to `mylayer-recipes` folder and now that works as expected